# Can you push the throttle forward while using reverse thrusters?

Tags: aircraft-design, thrust-reverser

Can you push the throttle forward while using reverse thrusters (for turbofans)? Does this have any effect, such as strengthen the "reverse" air blanket? Is it ever used?

Comment: What type of aircraft are you asking about?

Comment: I had some popular commercial turbofans in mind. E.g.: 737, 747, 777, 787, 320, 330, 350, 380. I've edited the question to specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On typical Boeing throttles, [this example being a 737NG](http://www.737ng.co.uk/tqfire5.jpg) but similar on all Boeings, the reverse thrust levers must be lifted to engage reverse.  In order to do this, the thrust levers must be in the idle gate and cannot be advanced until the reverse thrust levers as stowed.  The reverse levers engage locks in the thrust levers. [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO4Bxg8gh6Y), at 2:50, you can see the thrust levers being retarded to idle, then the reverse thrust levers being pulled up.  At 3:22 they are stowed.

[In this video from an A321](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xARCrvp3QE), you can see that the Airbus system is very similar.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the reverse thrust by pulling the reverse levels up halfway? Or must they be fully engaged to work at all?

Comment: The Airbus system does not strike me as particularly similar.

Answer (score 4):

In the B757 aircraft (RR engines), for example, the "reverse" thrust levers can only be raised/employed when the aircraft is on the ground and the "forward" thrust levers are in the idle stop position.  During reverse thrust operation, the forward thrust levers cannot be pushed forward.

This is different than many Turboprop airplanes

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  In reverse thrust, at idle, there is no effective thrust.  Advancing the throttle provides beta thrust.

Comment: Is it normally advanced all the way?

Comment: On which aircraft?  I've never heard of beta thrust.  Are you perhaps thinking of beta on turboprop aircraft? On Boeings and Airbus, advancing the thrust levers will stow the reversers.

Comment: Cessna 208B for a turboprop example.

Comment: I assume that the OP is asking about turbofans and turbojets.  We need to clarify.

Comment: A friend who flew B727 told me years ago about using their engines for push-back, and that certain airports had been upgraded to withstand the forces on the terminal building windows.  I suppose that would be an example of a non-turboprop.

Comment: @TayE reverse thrust should not exceed the torque limits. Also it is not approved for more than 60 seconds.  While it is very helpful managing taxi speed without brakes, and shortening landing lengths, some also use it for push back.  Personally, I have only done that with ground observers, although many pilots will clear the area behind them themselves prior to engine start.

Comment: @Terry, in the 727 if the clamshells are deployed, is there effective thrust?

Comment: Okay, I didn't see your qualification of when the reversers are deployed as to whether there is effective thrust in your answer. I don't know whether all 4 engines on the 747 with reversers deployed will start the airplane rolling, so I have deleted my comment. Sorry about that. I used to occasionally back up the 727. It always took a burst of power to break away, and then we reduced power considerably but I can't remember whether we went all the way to idle and kept moving.

Comment: @mongo, on occasion (mostly years ago) some aircraft operators would be authorized to do a "Powerback" from the gate in lieu of a normal "push back" with a tug.  Reverse thrust levers would be used to power the aircraft backwards. The big issue then was not with the terminal windows, but with the potential for the airplane to tip backward and strike the tail (improper use of the brakes).  That's why it required FAA approval and specific crew training for each operator.

Comment: Today I talked with a friend who frequently did push/power backs in the 727. The procedure involved a trained ground crew and a signed off capt. The ground observer would signal a small forward thrust, followed by reverse thrust. Slow movement. Then forward thrust to stop the backward movement. This saved tugs and tug operators, but required ramp FOD inspections, etc.